# How to add built-in assembly from .Net Core to a C# project in VS Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-assembly

How to add .Net Core built-in assembly, say, System.Windows.Forms, to a C# project in VS Code?

This can easily be done in Visual Studio by using the Reference Manager. However, I got stuck with VS Code. There is tutorial on how to add assembly from NuGet Package but I couldn't find one about adding .Net Core assembly.

Updated:
I tried what Nsevens said to have the following reference.

```
<ItemGroup>
     <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms">
      <HintPath>thePath\System.Windows.Forms.dll</HintPath>
     </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

There was no problem found in editor and it could be compiled successfully.

But, In debug mode the program vanishes immediately after starting debugging. Debug console says

The program '[(some number)] MyProgram.dll' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

If the exe is run directly, it fails and the console says

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution. They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (0x80131058)

Unhandled exception. System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (0x80131058)
File name: 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Cannot load a reference assembly for execution.
   at MyProgram.Program.Main(String[] args)

Comment: did you find the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to the project file (.csproj)

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="MyAssembly">
    <HintPath>path\to\MyAssembly.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

(from: https://medium.com/@tonerdo/referencing-a-net-dll-directly-using-the-net-core-toolchain-16f0af46a4dc)

Comment: Thanks. I tried this one but still failed. In debug mode the program vanishes immediately after starting debugging. If the exe is run directly, it fails and the console says
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution. They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (0x80131058)